# How to Merge Shapefile and Dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a spatial map showing drug mortality rates by US county, but I'm having trouble merging the drug mortality dataset, crude_rate, with the shapefile, usa_county_df. Can anyone help out?

I've created a key variable, "County", in both sets to merge on but I don't know how to format them to make the data mergeable. How can I make the County variables correspond? Thank you!

```
head(crude_rate, 5)
```

```
  Notes             County County.Code Deaths Population Crude.Rate
1       Autauga County, AL        1001     74     975679        7.6
2       Baldwin County, AL        1003    440    3316841       13.3
3       Barbour County, AL        1005     16     524875 Unreliable
4          Bibb County, AL        1007     50     420148       11.9
5        Blount County, AL        1009    148    1055789       14.0
```

```
head(usa_county_df, 5)
```

```
       long      lat order  hole piece id group County
1 -97.01952 42.00410     1 FALSE     1  0   0.1      1
2 -97.01952 42.00493     2 FALSE     1  0   0.1      2
3 -97.01953 42.00750     3 FALSE     1  0   0.1      3
4 -97.01953 42.00975     4 FALSE     1  0   0.1      4
5 -97.01953 42.00978     5 FALSE     1  0   0.1      5
```

```
crude_rate$County <- as.factor(crude_rate$County)

usa_county_df$County <- as.factor(usa_county_df$County)

merge(usa_county_df, crude_rate, "County")
```

```
 [1] County      long        lat         order       hole       
 [6] piece       id          group       Notes       County.Code
[11] Deaths      Population  Crude.Rate 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`
```

Comment: I found a relevant post on the GIS sister webside of stackoverflow.com. I think [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154761/merge-a-table-with-a-shapefile-not-the-same-dimension) is your solution.

Comment: In `crude_rate`, "County" is a string (the county name), but in `usa_county_df`, "County" is an integer. The two columns cannot be merged, since they do not contain values in common. Converting them both to factor data does not solve the problem, since there's no guarantee that the underlying numerical representations of the factors will match as expected. You need to find a map data set with labeled counties.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this. First, you cannot expect a full answer with code because you did not provide a link to you data. Next time, please provide a full description of the problem with the data.

I just used the data you provided here to illustrate.

```
require(tidyverse)

# Load the data
crude_rate = read.csv("county_crude.csv", header = TRUE)
usa_county = read.csv("usa_county.csv", header = TRUE)

# Create the variable "county_join" within the county_crude to "left_join" on with the usa_county data. Note that you have to have the same type of data variable between the two tables and the same values as well
crude_rate = crude_rate %>%
                 mutate(county_join = c(1:5))

# Join the dataframes using a left join on the county_join and County variables 
df_all = usa_county %>%
     left_join(crude_rate, by = c("County"="county_join")) %>%
     distinct(order,hole,piece,id,group, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Data link: [county_crude](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8w77138r0paj6s/county_crude.csv?dl=0)
Data link: [usa_county](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ph54gsniui0msz/usa_county.csv?dl=0)

> Blockquote